# How to make a function that counts the number of substrings in a string?

Tags: python, string

Define a function named how_many_substr_of_string(...) which receives two parameters, the first parameters is a list with strings (name it  listst) and the second parameter is a single string (name it st). The function should return a number, indicating how many of the strings in the list listst are substrings in the string st

As an example, the following code fragment:

```
listst = ["a","bc","dd"]
st = "abc"
res = how_many_substr_of_string(listst,st)
print (res)
```

should produce the output:
2

My code:

```
def how_many_substr_of_string(listst, st):
    return listst.count(st)
```

My code does not work for the following conditions and any other related conditions:

```
listst = ["a","bc","dd"]
st = "abc"
res = how_many_substr_of_string(listst,st)
print (res)
```

I get the output 0 but its supposed to be 2. How to fix this or edit my code such that it will work for this any other case as shown in the question

Answer (score 2):

```
def how_many_substr_of_string(listst, st):
    return sum(1 for item in listst if item in st)
```

A note on why this works even though strings are considered arrays - Python will use `__contains__(self, item)`, `__iter__(self)`, and `__getitem__(self, key)` in that order to determine whether an item lies in a given string.

Comment: whats the problem with my code? do you know why it wont work for the following condition i listed?

Comment: @harold232 That's because you're counting the number of times `st` occurs in `listst`, which is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
listst = ["a","bc","dd"]
s = "abc"
def how_many_substr(iterable, st):
    res = 0
    for i in iterable:
        if i in st: res += 1
    return res
print(how_many_substr(listst, s))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Your code was:

```
def how_many_substr_of_string(listst, st):
    return listst.count(st)
```

This counts the number of times `st` occurs in `listst`, which is 0.